# Share intent not working in android marshmallow

Tags: android, share-intent

I am using the below code for share content in android app, the code is working properly for android 7.+   but not working for marshmallow(6.0.1). please suggest.

```
shareNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
           Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
           String shareBody = Constants.SHARE_TEXT + refer_code;
           sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share");
           sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ShowToastMsg.showToast(getActivity(), "Error Occured");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be due to the runtime permission. Android **marshmallow** requires runtime permission for access the image files stored in the device. So you need to give runtime permission in code.

so make sure you are giving the required premissions like **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** and **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** so be careful before making request. And if you dont want to handle the permissions part here is way to do that.

```
// Provide read access
shareIntent.setData(uriToImage);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

there is a detailed guide how to use new features.  [Link](https://medium.com/google-developers/sharing-content-between-android-apps-2e6db9d1368b)

Please visit
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Note : You can also use the direct share [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/implementing-android-marshmallow-direct-share/) is tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem once,

I have added flag **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** and that worked fine.

Hope it will be useful to you.

Note: I got that error after signing apk, so may you have to check after sign your apk.